# R calculating the sum of values according to condition

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

Here is a data frame:

```
ID<-c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2), rep("C",3),rep("D",5))
cell<-c("a1","a2","a3","a1","a2","a1","a2", "a3","a1","a2","a1","a2","a3")
value<-c(2,5,3,4,5,6,9,8,7,2,5,2,4)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(ID, cell, value))
```

[image]

I want to calculate the sum of all values for each ID up to cell a2 (incl.). The sequence of cells and ID’s must be taken into account. If there isn’t any cell “a2” after calculating of the sum, this rows should not be taken into account.

[image]

As a result I would like to get this table:

[image]

Could You please help me to code this condition?
Thanks in advance.
Best regards, Inna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the file is already correctly ordered by cell

```
library( tidyverse )
df %>%
  group_by( ID ) %>%
  mutate( value = cumsum( value ) ) %>%
  filter( cell == "a2" )


# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups:   ID [4]
# ID    cell  value
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A     a2        7
# 2 B     a2        9
# 3 C     a2       15
# 4 D     a2        9
# 5 D     a2       16
```

Answer (score 1):

Treating each occurrence of `"a2"` as different group we can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Create a group column with every value of cell == 'a2' as different group
  group_by(ID, grp = cumsum(lag(cell == 'a2', default = TRUE))) %>%
  #Remove those groups that do not have 'a2' in them
  filter(any(cell == 'a2')) %>%
  #Sum till 'a2' value
  summarise(value =  sum(value[seq_len(match('a2', cell))]), 
            cell = last(cell)) %>%
  select(-grp)

#   ID    value cell 
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1 A         7 a2   
#2 B         9 a2   
#3 C        15 a2   
#4 D         9 a2   
#5 D         7 a2
```

Answer (score 1):

A succinct solution using `ave`.

```
r <- transform(df, value=ave(value, ID, FUN=cumsum))[df$cell == "a2", ]
r
#    ID cell value
# 2   A   a2     7
# 5   B   a2     9
# 7   C   a2    15
# 10  D   a2     9
# 12  D   a2    16
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, value := cumsum(value) , ID][cell == 'a2']
```

-output

```
#    ID cell value
#1:  A   a2     7
#2:  B   a2     9
#3:  C   a2    15
#4:  D   a2     9
#5:  D   a2    16
```